Functions passed as props to several functional components don't update common variables correctly
I have been working on a navbar functionality in next.js. I have two functions (for the mobile interface of the website) that respectively close and open the navbar, using a hamburger menu (for opening it) and an X icon on the navbar (for closing it). These two functions are defined inside the page export (see code below) and update local variables defined in the page export, after which they are passed down as props to the hamburger component and the navbar component.
The problem is that, upon changing the page from the navbar, the variable (isNavbarOpen) which holds the state of the navbar, is not updated anymore through the hamburger menu and is only updated when I close the navbar through the X icon inside of it.
The following is the index page function:
export default function Index() {
    ...
    var navbarPlayingAnim = false;
    var isNavbarOpen = false;
    ...
    function openNavbar() {
      

      var crntNavbarPos = -33;
  
      function frame() {
  
        if(crntNavbarPos >= 0) {
          navbarPlayingAnim = false;
          isNavbarOpen = true;
          navbarRef.current!.style.left = "0";
          clearInterval(AnimId)
        }
  
        else {
          crntNavbarPos = crntNavbarPos + 33 * frameRate/(1000*navbarAnimDuration);
          navbarRef.current!.style.left = String(crntNavbarPos) + "vw";
        }
  
  
      }
  
      if(!navbarPlayingAnim && !isNavbarOpen) {
        navbarPlayingAnim = true;
        var AnimId = setInterval(frame,1000*navbarAnimDuration/frameRate);
      }
  
    }
  
    function closeNavbar() {
  
      var crntNavbarPos = 0;
  
      function frame() {
  
        if(crntNavbarPos <= -33) {
          navbarRef.current!.style.left = "-33vw";
          navbarPlayingAnim = false;
          isNavbarOpen = false;
          clearInterval(AnimId)
        }
  
        else {
          crntNavbarPos = crntNavbarPos - 33* frameRate/(1000*navbarAnimDuration);
          navbarRef.current!.style.left = String(crntNavbarPos) + "vw";
        }
      }
  
      if(!navbarPlayingAnim && isNavbarOpen) {
        navbarPlayingAnim = true;
        var AnimId = setInterval(frame,1000*navbarAnimDuration/frameRate);
      }
    }
    ...
    return(
    ...
    <HamburgerBar openNavbarFunc={openNavbar}></HamburgerBar>
    <NavBar changePage={changePage} navbarRef={navbarRef} mainRef={mainRef} titleRef={titleRef} aboutRef={aboutRef} serviceRef={serviceRef} contactRef={contactRef} closeNavbarFunc={closeNavbar}></NavBar>
    ...)
}

Hamburger menu function:
  function HamburgerBar(props : {
    openNavbarFunc : MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>;
  }) {
  
    return (
      <div onClick={props.openNavbarFunc} className={styles.hamburgerIcon}>
        <ExportedImage src="/image/hamburger.png" alt="Hamburger logo" width={128} height={128} className={gC([styles.hamburgerImage,styles.unselectable])}></ExportedImage>
      </div>
    )
  }

Navbar function:
function NavBar(props: {
    navbarRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    mainRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    titleRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    aboutRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    serviceRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    contactRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
    changePage : (targetPage: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>, targetIndex: number) => void;
    closeNavbarFunc : MouseEventHandler<HTMLImageElement>
  }) {
  
    function NavBarButton(props: {
      targetName : string;
      targetRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
      targetIndex : number;
      mainRef : RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
      changePage : (targetPage: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>, targetIndex: number) => void;
      closeNavbarFunc : MouseEventHandler<HTMLImageElement>
    }) {
  
      function goToPage() {
        props.changePage(props.targetRef,props.targetIndex)
        props.closeNavbarFunc;
      }

      return (
        <div onClick={goToPage} className={styles.navbarButton}>
          <a className={styles.unselectable}>{props.targetName}</a>
        </div>
      )
    }
  
    return (
      <div ref={props.navbarRef} className={styles.navbar}>
        <div className={styles.fill}>
          <ExportedImage onClick={props.closeNavbarFunc} src="/image/x.png" alt="X Icon" width={64} height={64} className={styles.navbarX}></ExportedImage>
          <ExportedImage src="/image/logo.png" alt="FuzzyHosting Logo" width={128} height={128} className={styles.navbarImage}></ExportedImage>
        </div>
        <NavBarButton changePage={props.changePage} closeNavbarFunc={props.closeNavbarFunc} targetName="Acasă" targetRef={props.titleRef} targetIndex={0} mainRef={props.mainRef}></NavBarButton>
        <NavBarButton changePage={props.changePage} closeNavbarFunc={props.closeNavbarFunc} targetName="Despre noi" targetRef={props.aboutRef} targetIndex={1} mainRef={props.mainRef}></NavBarButton>
        <NavBarButton changePage={props.changePage} closeNavbarFunc={props.closeNavbarFunc} targetName="Servicii" targetRef={props.serviceRef} targetIndex={2} mainRef={props.mainRef}></NavBarButton>
        <NavBarButton changePage={props.changePage} closeNavbarFunc={props.closeNavbarFunc} targetName="Contact" targetRef={props.contactRef} targetIndex={3} mainRef={props.mainRef}></NavBarButton>
        <div className={styles.fill}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }

I defined the function for closing and opening the navbar inside the function for the index and passed them down as props. I expected them, upon being called in the functional components I passed them down to, to keep and update the variables defined inside the space where the openNavbar and closeNavbar functions were also defined, but this does not work.
Changing the page through the navbar menu and clicking the hamburger menu after that results in no change to the isNavbarOpen variable inside Index.

You need to use useState for state to be reactive. I would start from scratch and read the learn page of the docs.
